# UISplitViewController in Universal storyboard doesn't show both on screen on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus

I have implemented a `UISplitViewController` via Interface Builder in a Universal Storyboard. This is working really well - on iPad it shows both on screen at the same time, and on iPhone it shows only one on screen. But now apps that have implemented `UISplitViewController` will show both view controllers when the iPhone 6 Plus is rotated to landscape.

But in my application, that's not occurring automatically. Upon rotating to landscape it still only shows one view controller. What must I do in order to show both the master and detail side-by-side on iPhone 5 Plus in landscape?

Comment: Have you added the required iPhone 6 and 6+ launch images (or setup a launch screen file)? The 6+ needs both portrait and landscape.

Comment: I haven't yet. Odd, is that required or else it doesn't "optimize" for those devices or something?

Comment: Without the required launch images (or launch screen file), apps will be run as if they were on an iPhone 5 or 5S.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for apps to take full advantage of the iPhone 6 or 6+ screen size and for `UISplitViewController` to work as expected in landscape on the 6+, you must be sure to add the required iPhone 6 and 6+ launch images or setup a launch screen file.

Without those the app runs as if it is on an iPhone 5 or 5S (but scaled to fit the larger screen).

Comment: Quick question if I may: if I utilize a XIB for the launch image, does that appear when running iOS 7 as well?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the new Launch Screen File is only supported under iOS 8. Devices with iOS 7 wouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: You're correct, but you can have a launch screen and launch images if you're supporting both OSes.

Comment: Yes, you can have both. The Launch Screen file will be used for iOS 8 and the launch images will be used for anything earlier (and iOS 8 if you don't use the launch screen file).